# Finding the generation of a given object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, garbage-collection

Is it possible to find current [generation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#generations) of a given object? this is not an application requirement, just a curious question.

Comment: Memory profilers usually are able to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the `System.GC` class? It has a [`GetGeneration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts8yd2d0.aspx) method since .NET 2.0.